# why my question got closed?

Tags: discussion

I joined the community few days back and used 1 question to ask many. I got dinged ie got -1 from two experts saying i have asked too many. Fair enough, I edited that question to [Questions on Linux network driver and user mode driver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/764988/questions-on-linux-network-driver-and-user-mode-driver) which has 1 question

Why did I get a third -1 and on top of it, its closed saying its not clear. Want to understand what is not clear?

Appreciate the help

Comment: Forget the downvotes. No need to be expert to downvote and nobody can tell who downvoted. I personally did not take part in this thread but had seen it and had judged it far too broad to attempt an answer. Far too broad, I mean… like if I ask you who you are, this would be a very clear and unique question. But… certainly far too broad to be answered in a couple of lines, wouldn't it ? BTW, whoever you are… whatever your credit… welcome here :-)

Comment: Thanks MC. I was trying to understand how NUMA awareness is important for user mode driver. It would be good for the site to ask for a reason why someone is not answering but downvoting. Anyway thats a feature ask i guess :D

Answer (score 15):

Thank you for asking for input about your question.

When your question was closed, [it contained five separate questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/764988/1), each of an in-depth technical nature.  It was therefore closed as "unfocused".  Closing the question allows you to correct the issues that caused it to get closed. Editing a closed question puts it in the "re-open review queue".

You edited the text by deleting the four initial questions and [leaving only one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/764988/2).  However, this one question asks "IS NUMA awareness important? Yes/No why?".  This question has a few issues that prevent me (and presumably other reviewers too) from re-opening it.

1. It is subjective.  I.e., it depends on what you personally mean by "important".   What is important to you may not be important to me.  Something can also be important for stability, correctness, etc., possibly under certain circumstances, and it's unclear what *you* mean by the word and what your expectations may be.
2. It is open-ended.  Since it's subjective, an answer would have to take many different setups and scenarios into account and evaluate the pros and cons of each. It would be difficult to put boundaries to the scope of the issue.
3. It is unclear.  The question does not explain the issue with the resources you have previously found, making it harder to pinpoint the details you need help with.

I will not comment on why someone may have voted in any particular way on the question, as votes are private, and if they had wanted to leave a comment explaining their reasoning, they would have done so.

As I don't know anything about Linux-specific network or driver development etc. I can't unfortunately suggest how to rephrase the question suitably.